# Adding objects to List using Getters and Setters possible?

Tags: c#, .net, getter-setter

I want to return a list of databases from the method below. I want to use getters and setters so that `DatabaseName` and `ConnectionString` can be changed when this class Library is used and the `retrieveDatabaseList()` method is called.  I cant use the `getDatabase()` method because it only returns one instance of a database. I cant use the `set` method because it is void. Is there no way to use the getters and setters with the List.Add() method?

```
class SelectDatabase
{
    private string DatabaseName;
    private string ConnectionString;


    public SelectDatabase(string DBNAME, string CONNSTRING){


        DatabaseName = DBNAME;
        ConnectionString = CONNSTRING;

    }


    public List<SelectDatabase> retrieveDatabaseList()
    {


        List<SelectDatabase> databaseList = new List<SelectDatabase>();

        databaseList.Add(new SelectDatabase(getDatabaseName(),""));
        databaseList.Add( new SelectDatabase(getDatabaseName(), "" ));
        databaseList.Add( new SelectDatabase(getDatabaseName(), "" ));

        return databaseList;
    }

    public string getDatabaseName() {


        return this.DatabaseName;
    }

    public void setDatabaseName(string dbName) {

        this.DatabaseName = dbName;
    }

    public string getConnectionString()
    {


        return this.ConnectionString;
    }

    public void setConnectionString( string connectionString )
    {

        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you should learn about [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9fsa0sw.aspx) in C#, which eliminate the need for getter-setter methods.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve. So far the workflow is 1. create object, with database name and connection string. 2. Call `retrieveDatabaseList`, which creates three more instances of the same class, using the database name, but not the connection string, and it then returns that list. What were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Using the C# feature Properties you can make geting and seting the values of a class' fields really easy. Not sure if this is exactly what you wanted but this should give you a hint on how they work.

```
public class Database
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class Databases
{
    public ICollection<Database> DatabaseList { get; private set; }

    public void AddDatabase(Database db)
    {
        DatabaseList.Add(db);
    }

    public void RemoveDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        DatabaseList.Remove(DatabaseList.Single(db => db.Name == dbName));
    }
}
```

You should also read up on properties e.g. on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: Why make everything static? That just makes unit testing harder. Would be a +1 without the statics though.

Comment: Whoops, I've no idea why I did that. Fixed!

Comment: That's better :) I didn't really understand what the OP was after, but this code feels right somehow. Very nice encapsulation.